# 400 Bad Request with CURL

Tags: php, http, curl, vk

Today I tried to publish my site on the Internet and it turned out that CURL does not work for me. Everything worked fine on the local server

The first problem was generally related to the fact that the timeout constantly returned to me. I solved this problem with a proxy, but came across a new problem with 400 bad request

```
$headers = Array(
    'accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
);

$get_main_page = post('https://vk.com', Array(
    'headers' => Array(
        'accept: '.$headers['accept'],
        'content-type: '.$headers['content-type'],
        'user-agent: '.$headers['user-agent']
    )
));

function post($url = null, $params = null, $proxy = null, $proxy_userpwd = null) {
    $proxy = '91.77.162.117:8080';
    #$proxyauth = 'login:password';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

    $fOut = fopen($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/'.'curl_out.txt', "w" );
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fOut );

    if(isset($params['params'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params['params']);
    }

    if(isset($params['headers'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $params['headers']);
    }

    if(isset($params['cookies'])) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $params['cookies']);
    }

    if($proxy) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

        if($proxy_userpwd) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_userpwd);
        }
    }

    $result = curl_exec($ch); //original 
    #if(!$result = curl_exec($ch)) { //
    #   $result = curl_error($ch); //
    #}
    $result_explode = explode("\r\n\r\n", $result);

    $headers = ((isset($result_explode[0])) ? $result_explode[0]."\r\n" : '').''.((isset($result_explode[1])) ? $result_explode[1] : '');
    $content = $result_explode[count($result_explode) - 1];

    preg_match_all('|Set-Cookie: (.*);|U', $headers, $parse_cookies);

    $cookies = implode(';', $parse_cookies[1]);

    curl_close($ch);

    return Array('headers' => $headers, 'cookies' => $cookies, 'content' => $content);
}
```

Output:

```
* About to connect() to proxy 91.77.162.117 port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 91.77.162.117... * connected
* Connected to 91.77.162.117 (91.77.162.117) port 8080 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to login.vk.com:443
> CONNECT login.vk.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: login.vk.com:443
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36

< <html>
< <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
< <body bgcolor="white">
< <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
< <hr><center>nginx</center>
< </body>
< </html>
* Proxy CONNECT aborted
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: The problem is that this site blocks requests from my hosting, and when using a proxy, I get an HTTP error 400.

Comment: The proxy is returning the 400.  Most likely it doesn't support SSL and/or CONNECT.  Try another one and see if it works.